# Why AWS NLB doesn't need pre-warming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I learned that AWS NLB doesn't require pre-warming whereas CLB and ELB need.

> NLB is designed to handle tens of millions of requests per second while maintaining high throughput at ultra-low latency, with no effort on the customer's part. As a result, no pre-warm is needed.

from [Effective DevOps with AWS](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=bP1wDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232#v=onepage&q&f=false)

According to some relative information I found, NLB doesn't need pre-warming because it is designed to handle large amount of requests. On the other hand, ELB needs to scale up when the requests dramatically increased during a short period.

It makes sense but appears to be too general. I am curious what kind of difference in design brought this divergence. Is it because NLB focuses on L4 load balancing?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is NLB is a function of AWS HyperPlane, rather than running on servers, which makes it highly scaleable without warming.

You should watch the [Re:Invent NLB Deep Dive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0FBGIT1Ub4) to get a better understanding of NLB.